How to correctly effectively measure a low current and high current simultaneously
I've been tasked with implementing a high-side current measurement that should be able to measure low and high currents.
We're measuring current on the high-voltage side (we'll call it PGND) and the ADC is on a low voltage analog ground, so an isolated amplifier (TI AMC1302) will be used.
My circuit is basically below, with a stage that conditions the output signal to [0V, 2.5V],
where 0V is mapped to let's say -150A, and 2.5V is mapped to +150A.

These are the options:

Two current sense resistors in series (low resistance for high current, high resistance for low current), each with its own isolated amplifier channel
One current sense resistor, and adding another parallel path after the isolated amplifier with a different gain on the conditioning stage (for that channel I can map let's say [-50A, 50A] to [0, 2.5V]

Option one we gain better SNR in the output signal, but end up needing more PCB space for another resistor and another isolator channel
Second option, the outputs have the same SNR, but the ADC resolution should be better, and I should be saving more room on the PCB and component cost
Am I missing anything here in terms of my analysis or options?

Either in a series connection of shunt resistors the resistor for the low current range would be blown away at high current or, if not, you don't need the other one.

One technique is to short the low current shunt automatically when the current reaches a certain level.  Possibly with a relay, or a low RDSon FET if the off-state leakage is acceptable.
